# Como retornar registros relecionados entre tabelas em laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho 2 tabelas cidade e estado possuo o estado paraná e gostaria de saber como faço para retornar todas as cidades relacionadas ao  estado Parana de forma simples sem ter que fazer um laço de repetição

Tipo

```
$estados = App/Estado::all();
$cidades = App/Cidade::all();
foreach($estado as $estados)
{
    if($estado->id === $cidade->id)
    {
    }
}
```

não testei o código mas a maneira que sei seria essa tem alguma maneira mais simplificada

Comment: Primeiramente, bem vindo à comunidade. Existe forma mais simples sim, use os models :D vou preparar algo pra você em uma resposta, você poderia postar a estrutura das suas tabelas?

Comment: Cidade id nome fk_estado_id

Comment: Estado id nome sigla

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Vamos ao trivial:

rode os seguintes comandos:

`php artisan make:model Estado -crm`

`php artisan make:model Cidade -crm`

Desta forma você fará o model, migration e o controller em apenas um comando

Você terá as seguintes migrations:

- Estado

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEstadosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome',500);
            $table->string('sigla',2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('estados');
    }
}
```

- Cidade

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCidadesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cidades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('estado_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('nome',500);

            $table->foreign('estado_id')->references('id')->on('estados')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cidades');
    }
}
```

Dessa forma você já referenciou a chave estrangeira e definiu suas tabelas. Rode sua migration usando o comando `php artisan migrate`.

Abra o model `Cidade` e adicione o seguinte código:

```
public function Estado()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Estado','estado_id');
}
```

Abra o model `Estado` e adicione as seguintes linhas:

```
public function cidades()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cidade','estado_id');
}
```

Agora basta que você utilize as próprias ferramentas do laravel para que faça os filtros da forma que você precisa:

**Exemplo de uso aplicado em blade:**

```
@foreach($estados as $estado)
<tr>
    <td class='sua_classe_para_diferenciar'>{{$estado->nome}}</td>
</tr>
    @foreach($estado->cidades as $cidade)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$cidade->nome}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```